# Нужны ли кавычки в тексте прямой речи при зачитывании вслух (письмо, документ, надпись и пр.)?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, прямая-речь, редактура, цитирование

В книге "Гарри Поттер и Кубок огня" издательства "РОСМЭН-ПРЕСС" 2002 г. заметил, что по всему тексту в репликах, в которых персонаж зачитывает с бумажки, его фразы, помимо диалогового тире, выделены ещё и кавычками, как цитаты. Однако нигде не нашёл такого правила. В "Нацкорпусе" гораздо чаще встречается выделение кавычками, но и примеры без них тоже там есть.

Так вот, скажите, если герой книги читает вслух, зачитывает письмо, озвучивает надпись (при этом ещё может вставлять междометия, паузы, вопросительные/восклицательные интонации, которые меняют зачитываемое) — в таком случае как быть, кавычки всё-таки излишни, это редакторская вольность? Или же их наличие в подобных случаях факультативно/обязательно? Вот отдельные фрагменты из книги.

**1-й фрагмент**

*Пламя вновь покраснело, и Кубок выстрелил ещё одним куском пергамента.*

*— "Чемпион Шармбатона — Флер Делакур!" — возвестил Дамблдор.*

*— Смотри, Рон! — крикнул Гарри. — Это она!*

**2-й фрагмент**

*Из Кубка вылетел третий кусок пергамента. Дамблдор поймал его и прочитал:*

*— "Чемпион Хогвартса — Седрик Диггори".*

*— Ну почему он?! Почему? — возопил Рон.*

**3-й фрагмент**

*Повисла длинная пауза. Дамблдор смотрел на пергамент, весь зал смотрел на него. Наконец он кашлянул и прочитал:*

*— "Гарри Поттер".*

Ну а если кавычки всё же нужны, что делать с неточным цитированием (которое перемежается междометиями, какими-то вставками зачитывающего)? Тот же Дамблдор, судя по всему, от себя добавляет восклицательный знак (интонацию) во фразу "...Флер Делакур!". Разве не логичнее вынести этот знак за пределы кавычек? Ну а в таком случае, где цитирование перемежается всяческими междометиями (звукоподражаниями), как закавычивать?

*Леона присела и зачитала письмо вслух:*

*— (")Уиллис, как же долго я тебя... ждала(")?..*

*Лицо Леоны исказилось, а голос стал на тон выше, но она продолжила, запинаясь:*

*— (")В Хьюстоне... кхм... прекрасная погода... Но я не эм... могу заставить себя... выйти из дома...(")*

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

"Грамма.ру" в ответе на вопрос № 9693 говорит, что в подобных случаях *"кавычки избыточны, так как указание на то, что реплика является цитатой, содержится в словах автора..."* (см. [здесь](http://gramma.ru/ARR/)).

"Грамота.ру" ответила на схожий вопрос № 309779, что *"...кавычки обязательны"* (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20309779)).

Что ж, я склонен верить "Грамоте.ру", значит, кавычки в таких случаях всё же ставим.

Comment: Но ведь даже у именитых писателей не всегда выделяется кавычками реплика, если она зачитывается, вот и не понимаю... Почему так?                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                          — Пункт шестой, — нерешительно зачитал комендант. — Образование: высшее син... кри... кре... кретическое. (Аркадий и Борис Стругацкие. Сказка о Тройке)

Comment: Это вопрос к именитым авторам. В Нацкорпусе примеров с кавычным выделением цитаты внутри реплики много. Там и Булгаков есть, и Платонов.

Comment: А вот "Грамма.ру" говорит, что в подобных случаях "кавычки избыточны, так как указание на то, что реплика является цитатой, содержится в словах автора..." (см. вопрос 9693, http://gramma.ru/ARR/i_num.php). Посмотрим, ответит ли на этот вопрос и "Грамота.ру".

Comment: Я всё же поспешил принять ответ, потому что он противоречит тому, что я нашёл на "Грамме.ру", и решил отменить принятие... Пока что не могу понять однозначно, кто прав, посмотрим. Очень жду ответа "Грамоты.ру", но она молчит.

Comment: В Нацкорпусе  большинство примеров с кавычками, вы можете найти без кавычек?  Например: Ну это он умеет, ― равнодушно согласился Гуляев, ожидая, пока Нейман встанет и уступит ему своё место, ― этому-то мы его обучили! ― Он сел, вынул блокнот и положил его перед собой. ― «Полина Юрьевна Потоцкая, ― прочитал он, ― сотрудница Ветзооинститута» ― говорит вам это что-нибудь? [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 4 (1978)]  Здесь в одной фразе есть прочитанный и собственный текст.

Comment: И откуда у Граммы.ру полномочия решать подобные вопросы, их объяснение – это всего лишь мнение, к тому же в данном случае противоречащее практике. По-моему, вы спешите  и принимать, и отменять приемку ответов.  К чему такая суетливость, она вам уважения не прибавит.  К тому же вы задаете вопросы во многих местах, так, может, начинать лучше с авторитетных источников, а уж потом, интереса ради, опрашивать остальные?

Comment: Без кавычек находил, у Стругацких выше, например, в комментарии. Ни на что не претендую, вижу, что кавычки часто ставят в таких случаях, просто хочу разобраться, это факультативно или строго по правилу цитирования. "Грамота.ру" молчит, как всегда, а все вопросы сперва задаю ей, потом дублирую здесь. Возможно, спешу, да. Такой уж нервозный характер, хочется узнать правильный ответ, чтобы в дальнейшем знать, как поступать.

Comment: Да, спешите, но это ваша проблема. Я же обращаюсь к вам с просьбой не менять принятые решения. Даже если вы получили ответы от справочных служб, это не касается нашей работы. Знак принятия ответа  не означает, что это абсолютная истина,  но и Справки  тоже не дают гарантированно верный ответ. Вы  можете позже добавить полученную информацию,  ничего не меняя здесь. И где, как вы считаете,  можно найти "строго правильный ответ"?  Какой у вас критерий для этого? Я, к примеру, считаю, что это соответствие практике + логическое доказательство выбора. Думаете, справочные службы пришлют вам всё это?

Comment: Могут и не прислать, да. Поэтому хочется ориентироваться на ответ, который является аргументированным и развёрнутым, с примерами из практики, учитывающим нюансы, указанные в вопросе. Это позволит иметь почву под ногами при принятии решения в тексте. В данном вопросе, в частности, мне важно понять, почему встречаются оба варианта оформления, хотя и с разной частотностью; что на это влияет; какой из этого можно сделать вывод по допустимости того или иного варианта. Сделать логичный вывод самому без опыта и теоретической подготовки не представляется возможным. Иначе бы не задавал свои вопросы)))

Comment: Вот  вы получили ответ от Грамма.ру, он показался вам убедительным, чему-то научил? Целесообразность – вот надежный критерий. Кавычки дают нам возможность отличать читаемый текст в любом варианте: когда пропущено слово "прочитал",  когда в одной фразе соединен читаемый и собственный текст. Это тот случай, когда еднообразие в оформлении  существенно важно. Нам достаточно вариативности при оформлении самой прямой речи, пусть хоть что-то будет постоянным. А Грамма.ру просто отписалась, дав первый пришедший в голову ответ. Я тут про вашего "комара"  вспомнила, отмахнулась короче, ага. :))

Comment: Ну хорошо, то есть в целом вы считаете, что в данном случае лучше, конечно, выделять, но и отсутствие кавычек, если уж на то пошло, не будет ошибкой, это допустимо? Правильно ли я вас понял, если обобщить?

Comment: Как сказать... Основное правило – это выделение читаемого текста кавычками, так мы гарантированно определяем, что он именно читаемый. Мне кажется, что даже чисто психологически они необходимы своей наглядностью. Я не могу сказать, что исключения невозможны ни при каких-то обстоятельствах. Но я пока не вижу этих обстоятельств, не могу представить, каковы они. Но это всего лишь вероятные частные случаи. И все-таки любопытно, какой ответ вы получите от Грамоты.ру.

Comment: На этот вопрос они мне не отвечают уже больше 2 месяцев, но я не теряю надежды и упорно задаю им его каждый божий день (как и прочие пока что остающиеся без ответа).

Comment: Посмотрела Стругацких – и мне не понравилось! https://mir-knig.com/read_283464-76 Да там с трудом разберешь, что читают, а что говорят. По объему читаемый текст небольшой, он прерывается разговорами, так почему бы его не выделить кавычками! И глаголы разные, не только "читает" (сказал, забарабанил". В общем, неудачный это пример с отсутствием кавычек. Единственное, на что можно сослаться, это то, что тема и канцелярский стиль читаемого текста  как-то выделяется на фоне разговоров. Но это только в оправдание этого частого случая. Здесь еще надо смотреть, как будет выглядеть графика с кавычками.

Comment: @Sharon, "Грамота.ру" ответила на схожий вопрос, что кавычки нужны (см. дополнение к вопросу).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если персонаж что-то читает с листа, то, конечно, кавычки должны быть, ведь это цитата, пусть и внутри реплики.
То есть если на бумажке из Кубка Огня значился буквально тот текст, который зачитал Дамблдор: "Чемпион Шармбатона — Флер Делакур!", "Чемпион Хогвартса — Седрик Диггори" и "Гарри Поттер" — то кавычки стоят по правилам.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> — Перестаньте, Олексин. Перестаньте перекладывать на достойного офицера свое беспутство. Знаете, как вас полковой командир
> охарактеризовал? — Генерал извлек очередную бумажку и зачитал почти с
> выражением: — "Картежник и бретер, игрок и дуэлянт". Куда ближе к
> действительности, нежели старческие сантименты Инзова...
> *(Борис Васильев)*

> Ему дали книгу.
> Он положил ее перед собой и стал ощупывать пальцами.
> И с треском открыл, тут же ткнув пальцем.
> И зачитал вслух:
> — «Слаповский Алексей Иванович. Впервые шумный успех выпал на долю
> саратовского прозаика и драматурга в 1994 г., хотя к этому времени он
> давным-давно печатался, а пьесы его шли во многих театрах российской
> провинции. Именно в тот год Слаповский (которого столь авторитетный
> критик, как А. Немзер, считает одним из самых значительных писателей
> поколения) попал в список финалистов английской премии Букера за
> лучший русский роман года. Он, филигранно, мастерски владеющий
> искусством построения авантюрного сюжета, умеющий блеснуть недюжинным
> умом и не чуждый иронии, считался одним из главных претендентов на
> премию. И даже признание председателя жюри критика Л. Аннинского, не
> скрывавшего, что сознательно (и вполне удачно) противодействовал
> „лауреатству“ Слаповского, даже это воспринималось как своего рода
> негативная составляющая успеха. Где удача, там неприязнь, вражда, а
> подчас и зависть. (В том числе зависть уходящего поколения к энергии и
> силе „восходящих звезд“.)»
> – Ну хватит! – перебил раздраженно Парфен.
> – Чего он сочинил-то?
> *(Алексей Слапковский)*