# Как оформлять текст в диалоге, если персонаж читает книгу?

Tags: прямая-речь, цитата

Например, персонаж берёт в руки книгу и начинает вслух читать текст, который там написан. Как такой диалог правильно оформляется? Надо ли брать читаемый текст в кавычки? Например:

> — Что там написано? — спросил Олег.
>
> — «Если вы нашли эту книгу, значит, я уже мёртв», — прочитал Андрей. —
> «Еды уже не осталось, вода закончится через несколько дней».
>
> Андрей посмотрел на Олега и произнес:
>
> — Это же записи Крантакрана!

Comment: Это обсуждалось недавно: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470914/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BD

Comment: @Nektoid спасибо, сейчас почитаю.

Comment: Там пока не получилось однозначно разобраться. Nektoid привёл убедительные доводы и примеры в пользу кавычек, но "Грамма.ру" говорит, что кавычки излишни при наличии слов автора, указывающих на зачитывание вслух, и примеры тому тоже есть... "Грамота.ру" же не отвечает уже давно на подобный мой вопрос...

Comment: @ShiKomarishe Грамма.ру -- неофициальный проект двух преподавателей и одного программиста. Их ответы никоим образом не могут составлять конкуренцию массиву текстов, в том числе классиков, из Нацкорпуса.